# How to stop an animation in C# / WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have something like this:

```
barProgress.BeginAnimation(RangeBase.ValueProperty, new DoubleAnimation(
    barProgress.Value, dNextProgressValue,
    new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dDuration)));
```

Now, how would you stop that animation (the `DoubleAnimation`)? The reason I want to do this, is because I would like to start new animations (this seems to work, but it's hard to tell) and eventually stop the last animation...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To stop it, call `BeginAnimation` again with the second argument set to `null`.

Comment: Be careful. This doesn't work if you specify HandoffBehavior.Compose. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590757%28v=VS.90%29.aspx for details. Pay attention to the doco for the animation parameter.

Comment: Calling `BeginAnimation` a second time doesn't seem to stop the Animation "clock" of the first animation from going on. After the specified time the animation raises the `Completed` event. Is is not raised directly when calling `BeginAnimation` but rather when the Animation *would have finished*.

Comment: Please show me how to set second argument to null  in vb.net??? `myStoryboard.Begin(containingObject:=Me, isControllable:=True, handoffBehavior:=Animation.HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace)`

Comment: @HerryMarkowitz in vb.net use the keyword `Nothing`. -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing

Answer (score 36):

When using storyboards to control an animation, make sure you set the second parameter to true in order to set the animation as controllable:

```
public void Begin(
    FrameworkContentElement containingObject,
    **bool isControllable**
)
```

Comment: Plus one to you, I was wondering why my animation did not respond to "Stop"!

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, this did it. That missing "true" was driving me nuts :)

Comment: you are a legend! this was driving me crazy!

Comment: The question concerns Animations, not Storyboards (as this answer responds).

Answer (score 18):

There are two ways to stop a BeginAnimation.  The first is to call BeginAnimation again with the second parameter set to null.  This will remove all animations on the property and **revert** the value back to its base value.

Depending on how you are using that value this may not be the behavior you want.  The second way is to set the animations BeginTime to null then call BeginAnimation with it.  This will remove that specific animation and leave the value at its current position.

```
DoubleAnimation myAnimation = new Animation();
// Initialize animation
...

// To start
element.BeginAnimation(Property, myAnimation);

// To stop and keep the current value of the animated property
myAnimation.BeginTime = null;
element.BeginAnimation(Property, myAnimation);
```

Comment: I agree.  This answers the question, applying specifically to the OPs request for Animations, not a Storyboard, and provides two good options.

Comment: Note again, this does not work if you are using `HandoffBehavior.Compose`.

Answer (score 11):

```
<Trigger.EnterActions>
       <BeginStoryboard x:Name="myStory">
       .........
       </BeginStoryboard>
</Trigger.EnterActions>
<Trigger.ExitActions>
       <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="myStory"/>
</Trigger.ExitActions>
```

Comment: StopStoryBoard is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

Comment: @SimonSmith `StopStoryBoard` is supported in WPF!

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had to use two commands, my xaml has a button which fires a trigger, and its trigger fires the storyboard animation.

I've put a button to stop animation with this code behind:

```
MyBeginStoryboard.Storyboard.Begin(this, true);
MyBeginStoryboard.Storyboard.Stop(this);
```

I don't like it but it really works here. Give it a try!

Comment: Remember to call Storyboard.Remove(this) as well, or you may leak memory since your FrameworkElement will keep a reference to the storyboard. I just found an instance in my code where just stopping and replacing the animation left 4000+ animations rooted after running for some weeks.

Answer (score 8):

> If you want the base value to become
>   the effective value again, you must
>   stop the animation from influencing
>   the property. There are three ways to
>   do this with storyboard animations:
>
> - Set the animation's FillBehavior
>     property to Stop
> - Remove the entire Storyboard
> - Remove the animation from the
>     individual property

From MSDN

[How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Place the animation in a StoryBoard.  Call Begin() and Stop() on the storyboard to start to stop the animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
[StoryBoardName].Remove([StoryBoardOwnerControl]);
```