# WPF after animation events stop working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation

I have a simple window where the user scans a barcode and you get an animation based on the barcode.

after the first animation it stops receiving the Window_KeyDown event.

The animation is triggered via code because it needs to read the barcode.

This is the storyboard.

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="Win">
        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="txtbScan">
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:05" Value="Scan your barcode"/>
        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Here i call in code.

```
                Dim win As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("Win"), Storyboard)
                txtbScan.Text = "Hurray you won " & GetPrize(curBarcode)
                win.Begin(Me)
```

It looks like the animation continues and cannot receive the next input event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop an animation in C# / WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298/how-to-stop-an-animation-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a weirdness with WPF. Animations don't clear until you call a `null` animation on the animated property. Try this:

```
// You have to run a 'null' animation to clear an animated property
win.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.TextProperty, null)
```

something to that effect. (Not sure how to properly format VB).

**Edit**:

Take a look at this [How to stop an animation in C# / WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298/how-to-stop-an-animation-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Comment: Or just set the animation's [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) property to `Stop`.