# How to stop DoubleAnimation on mouseover event?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, marquee, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I have two canvases and a textblock with name tbmarquee, on window load it animates from top to bottom, but i want to stop when i over the mose on it, and when i click it goes to the link, how to do it ?

```
 void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualHeight;
        doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualHeight;
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:10"));
        tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, doubleAnimation);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On mouse over event handler of `tbmarquee`, call `BeginAnimation()` again with second argument set to `null` to stop the animation :

```
tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, null);
```

Related question : [How to stop an animation in C# / WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298/how-to-stop-an-animation-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Comment: adding the above code i.e calling BeginAnimation() again with null argument simply stop the animation on top without MouseOver event and it wont animate..